# Heroku Maintenance has changed my DATABASE_URL I have access to a foreign DB

Tags: python, heroku

I am using heroku for 3 years now. And today for one of my app I recieved first time a "Maintenance (DATABASE_URL on my-project) has completed successfully." email.

But my site is completely down with this error:

```
Aug 21 19:55:16 my-project app[web] FATAL psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "kfwefwfcwere"
Aug 21 19:55:16 my-project app[web] FATAL FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "kfwefwfcwere"
```

So I am trying to figure out whats wrong and I see that my DATABASE_URL is a new one which is not mine. I also cant change it, because I get:

```
Cannot overwrite attachment values DATABASE_URL.
```

What do I do now? Someone had this before?

**EDIT**

I checked through pgAmdin whether I really have access to a foreign DB and it seems no, I get the same error there:

```
password authentication failed for user "kfwefwfcwere"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the issue. It seems that this is new in heroku for hobby, dev and standard tiers. In the maintenance heroku changes the DB credentials for your DB and it should update the config var automatically but in my case it failed and my site was down.

I was confused because when I checked my DB credentials through the heroku website it still showed me my old credentials, so it looked like I had access to a foreign DB.

The biggest issue was ofc. that my site was down for several hours until I noticed.

I simply had to change in my `config.py` the DATABASE_URL to the new one, which I found in `heroku config`